# Safari doesn't send cookie to Express when requesting image via p5 loadImage()

Tags: express, safari, p5.js, express-session

## Background

I set up an **Express.js app behind a proxy** to let users to login before being directed to a web app. This **app is failing to serve up some images in Safari (macOS/iOS) because Safari is not sending the cookie back with requests for images** that originate from the `loadImage()` method in my p5.js code. This does not happen on Chrome (macOS).

When I load the page, the browser requests the resources fine. But requests originating from my application returns a different session, which is not logged in, and gets caught by Express:

```
// Request for the main page by the browser
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2020-05-04T16:26:00.291Z,
     originalMaxAge: 259199998,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true },
  loggedin: true }

// Request for image assets by a script in my application
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2020-05-04T16:26:00.618Z,
     originalMaxAge: 259200000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true } }
```

### HTTP Requests from Safari

```
GET https://mydomain/app/img/svg/Water.svg HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain
Origin: https://mydomain
Connection: keep-alive
If-None-Match: W/"5e6-171c689d240"
Accept: image/png,image/svg+xml,image/*;q=0.8,video/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 29 Apr 2020 15:24:13 GMT
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: https://mydomain/app/
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 01 May 2020 06:50:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/7.3.17
X-Powered-By: Express
Location: /
Vary: Accept
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 23
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive

Found. Redirecting to /
```

### Express app

The app is set up behind an HTTPS proxy, so I set the Express Session object to trust proxy and set security to auto (setting to false doesn't fix the problem):

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
app.use(session({
    secret: 'my-secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: 'auto',
        maxAge: 259200000
    }
}));
```

When the user signs in, it is sent to `/auth` to check against the database

```
app.post('/auth', function (request, response) {
    var user = request.body.user;
    var password = request.body.password;

    if (user && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user = ? AND password = ?', [user, password], function (error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {

                request.session.loggedin = true;

                // If the user logs in successfully, then register the subdirectory
                app.use("/app", express.static(__dirname + '/private/'));

                // Then redirect
                response.redirect('/app');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect password!');
            }
            response.end();

            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});
```

They are redirected to `/app` when logged in:

```
app.all('/app/*', function (request, response, next) {

    if (request.session.loggedin) {    
        next(); // allow the next route to run
    } else {
        // The request for images from my p5 script fails and these request redirect to "/"
        response.redirect("/");
    }
})
```

## Question

What can I do to ensure Safari pass the session cookie with its request so that Express will return the correct asset?

---

#### Edit

Including the function that invokes `loadImage()`. This is embedded in an ES6 class that loads image assets for particles in a chemical simulation. This class must successfully resolve promises so other higher order classes can set correct properties.

```
loadParticleImage() {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        loadImage(this.imageUrl, (result) => {

            // Resolves the Promise with the result
            resolve(result);

        }, (reason) => {

            console.log(reason);
        });
    })
}
```

#### Edit #2

Including the headers for a successful request directly to the URL of the image asset:

```
GET https://mydomain/app/img/svg/Water.svg HTTP/1.1
Host: mydomain
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3A2frOCv41gcVRf1J4t5LlTcWkdZTdc8NT.8pD5eEHo6JBCHcpgqOgszKraD7AakvPsMK7w2bIHlr4
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Comment: Please show the `loadImage()` client code.

Comment: You've shown headers of the failing request. Please show headers of the correct request as well.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 I added the specific function call. It's pretty barebones, returns a promise that resolves the result of `loadImage()` so that other classes wait to access properties until they're defined.

Comment: @CoderFF I've included the successful headers in Edit #2 when I access the file directly in the browser

Comment: I was asking for the actual code that causes the GET request to be sent from the browser which you still aren't showing.  I want to see the actual Ajax call.  You still aren't showing that.

Comment: Another question: is your image a static file, i.e. is it generated with some code, or it's just there on the disk?

Comment: @jfriend00 Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but `loadImage()` is a method provided by p5.js (https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/06e48de066e8e797e4291f2a8cb2bd95edef9e31/src/image/loading_displaying.js#L65)

Comment: @CoderFF It's just on disk, created it in Illustrator as a static image asset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using [express's static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to serve static files. With this, you won't need any session to get images, js, css, etc. Also, it accelerates your application. You need to place

```
app.use(express.static( ... ))
```

before the `app.use(session( ... ))` statement if you want some additional perfomance, because if you do, express won't attepmt to creare session for static files.

Comment: I had initially tried to do this, but I now realize I was serving up the root of the application (making the login session moot). Didn't occur to me to selectively serve up subfolders as static. This fixed the issue.

Comment: I removed all my comments.

Answer (score 2):

The `fetch()` call in the [source code](https://github.com/processing/p5.js/blob/06e48de066e8e797e4291f2a8cb2bd95edef9e31/src/image/loading_displaying.js#L75) for that `loadImage()` function is not setting [the `credentials` option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/credentials) that controls whether cookies are included with the request or not, therefore they are not sent with the request.

Do you really need authentication before serving an image?  If not, you could rearrange the way you serve images in your server so that they can be served without authentication using `express.static()` pointed at a directory that contains only resources that can be served without authentication.  If they do need to be authenticated, you may have to patch the `loadImage()` code to use the `credentials: include` option or load your images a different way.

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I'll point this out to the p5 team, since I'm sure others will have the same problem on Safari.

Comment: @dfd0226 - I'm curious that the answer that got to the bottom of what was actually happening here was not considered your most helpful answer?